# SAS: Match single word within string values of a single variable then replace entire string value with a blank

Tags: string, substring, sas

I'm working in SAS 9.2, in an existing dataset. I need a simple way to match a single word within string values of a single variable, and then replace entire string value with a blank.  I don't have experience with SQL, macros, etc. and I'm hoping for a way to do this (even if the code is less efficient" that will be clear to a novice.

Specifically, I need to remove the entire string containing the word "growth" in a variable "pathogen."  Sample values include "No growth during two days", "no growth," "growth did not occur," etc. I cannot enter all possible strings since I don't yet know how they will vary (we have only entered a few observations so far).

TRANSWD and TRANSLATE will not work as they will not allow me to replace an entire phrase when the target word is only a part of the string.

Other methods I've looked at (for example, a SESUG paper using PRX at http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2007/CC06.pdf) appear to remove all instances of the target string in every variable in the dataset, instead of just in the variable of interest.

Obviously I could subset the dataset to a single variable before I perform one of these actions and then merge back, but I'm hoping for something less complicated. Although I will certainly give something more complicated a shot if someone can provide me with sample code to adapt (and it would be greatly appreciated).

Thanks in advance--Kim

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point but does `if index(upcase(pathogen),'GROWTH') then pathogen='';` work?

Comment: That worked perfectly and was easy! Thank you, mjsqu.  I think this is one of those cases of being unable to come up with the exact Google search that would pinpoint what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Could you be a little more clear on who the data set is constructed? I think mjsqu's solution will work if your variable pathogen is stored sentence by sentence. If not then I would say your best bet is to parse the blocks into sentences and then apply mjsqu's solution.

```
DATA dataset1;
    format Ref best1.
        pathogen $40.;
    input Ref pathogen $40. ;
datalines;
1 No growth during two days
2 no growth,
3 growth did not occur,
4 does not have the word
;
RUN;

DATA dataout;
    SET dataset1;
    IF index(lowcase(pathogen),"growth") THEN pathogen="";
RUN;
```

Comment: Thanks lamecicle, the dataset was constructed pretty much as you outlined it in your response, so mjsqu's solution worked without any other manipulations. Thanks for posting the code as an example to clarify for others, though.